# how to show custom error page in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I would like to use custom error page (`src/error.js`) as described in https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#customizing-the-error-page

But my own (`src/error.js`) error page doesn't show on API server errors.

Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/github/lumpov/react-admin/master

Click on `error`-resource.

How to catch API errors on custom page, instead bottom notifications?

Environment

React-admin version: 4.6.2
React version: 18.2.0

Comment: Do you get an error in the dev console?

Comment: @Woodchuck, nop